# Coding multiple Piezos in C#

Tags: c#, arduino

Can anyone help me write this function? I need to be able to play two different tones at once on two different Piezos. What should I change my code to?

```
void beep (unsigned char speakerPin, int freq1, int freq2, long timeInMilliseconds) 
{
  int x;      
  long delayAmount1 = (long)(1000000/freq1);
  long delayAmount2 = (long)(1000000/freq2);
  long loopTime = (long)((timeInMilliseconds*1000)/(delayAmount1*2));
  for (x=0;x<loopTime;x++)    
  {    
    digitalWrite(speakerPin1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(speakerPin2,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(delayAmount2);
    digitalWrite(speakerPin1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(speakerPin2,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(delayAmount2);

  }   
}
```

Comment: We cannot write the code for you. Need to try something first yourself, and tell us about it.

Comment: It seems like a "Piezo" is important to this. What is it?

Comment: I know that I would be able to write the code using a shift register but I don't want to have to use a shift register. All I have plugged into my arduino right now is just the two Piezos. This is what I've come up with so far.

Comment: Piezos are instruments that turn electricity into mechanical energy in order to create tones. This somewhat explains what it is, but I'm not using the code given there. http://wlendrum.ca/2014-2015%20Classes/CS%2030/Labs/Lab%207a%20Referance%20Musuc%20Piezo.pdf

Comment: What is wrong with what you have now? What is the implementation of `digitalWrite` and `delayMicroseconds`? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Right now both Piezos are playing the same tone. The    delayMicroseconds is what is causing it to be the tone that it is. I need some way for them to play different tones, but at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using timers and interrupts. They will provide more accurate timing, and run independently of `loop()`.

There is already an Arduino function, `tone()` that plays one note at a time, but it can't be adapted to more than one, because it relies on the PWM of a single timer.

Instead, you need to write an interrupt service routine that toggles a pin at the right time and sets up the next interrupt to fire at the appropriate time in the future. You will need to use `attachInterrupt()`, and have some global `volatile` variables to manipulate the tones.

This is a standard student exercise, and there should be lots of examples on the web.

Comment: Would you mind finding me an example of this? I've been looking for about 4 hours now with no luck.

Comment: Also, would it be possible to run a shift register instead? And then I could run the speakers in parallel?

Comment: http://www.jeremyblum.com/2010/09/05/driving-5-speakers-simultaneously-with-an-arduino/ is a simple one with "good enough" precision. There must be many more with more precision to the tones. But the code does show you how to set up an interrupt handler and configure the timer to use it. I just searched "arduino timers tones" and ignored the hits that used `tone()`.